# how to tree shake unused styles from codebase

Tags: css, reactjs, unused-variables

I want to remove all the unused css rules from my codebase. My code is mostly like:

> index.js (which import a sibling styles.css - and binds with withStyles) 
>   styles.css (which has css rules to apply to the sibling index.js file)

Is it possible to do a regex based search in a javascript file created from the corresponding css file

Answer (score 1):

you can use (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/purifycss-webpack) plugin to do it.

**UPDATE**

lib author recommends https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss-webpack-plugin
this package instead of purifycss

Answer (score 0):

[Chrome DevTools CSS Coverage](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#coverage)

Not exactly what you are looking for but may be helpful